# Plotting Graphs using TIFF images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I am currently working on Matlab and stuck at a point where I have to plot the graphs using the data using TIFF images. I have gone through the help file which is imread but was unable to find the proper steps.

I will be very thankful if someone can post the proper guide lines.

Regards,

Sam

Comment: This doesn't work for you: `[X,map] = imread('your_image.tif')`?

Comment: Could you give more details about the problem, such as to what graphs you want to plot? Or do you just want to display a tiff image?

Comment: Are you trying to save the plot as a tiff image?

Comment: @cyborg: I have tried using the same command which you have suggested me. But while plotting the graph it shows the error saying "vectors must be the same lengths"

Comment: @ Bill Cheatham : I have certain group of TIFF images saved using special kind of camera. I want to analyse them regarding what difference will light and distance make through the graph.

Comment: @SAM , you can show us the code that generates the error. Please delete all the lines that are not necessary to recreate the error.

Comment: @cyborg:The code goes like this:      [X,map]= imread('1.tiff');
                                      plot(X,map)
                                      ??? Error using ==> plot
                                      Vectors must be the same lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to load a tiff and show it, as explained in [Matlab's `imread` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html):

```
[X,map]= imread('1.tiff'); 
image(X); 
colormap(map);
```